# How to use dplyr NSE inside an if condition inside a function?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr, nse

I have a function which takes an NSE argument.

Let's say I have a tibble with a column that needs ordering. I want to create a function that can order the name of the column based on the name inputted in the function argument.
However I want it to not order the column if I don't use the argument, hence I use `column_name = NULL` as a default argument (or `column_name = NA`)

```r
sort_tibble <- function(column_name = NULL) {
  tibble_data <- tibble::tibble(NSE_name = c(0.2, -0.4, 1.7, 0.09, -0.6, -1))
  if (!is.null(({{ column_name }}))) {
    tibble_data <- tibble_data %>% arrange({{ column_name }})

    # Do stuff
  }
}

sort_tibble(NSE_name)
#> Error in sort_tibble(NSE_name): objet 'NSE_name' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However despite how many combinations of quote, {{var}} or rlang::eval_tidy, I can't find an idea to make R understand that column_name is not empty (thus used). It can't find it because it's not a variable but a tidy evaluation, except it's not used in a tidy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution !

The idea here is not to directly try to inject the data for dplyr using {{var}} but to first use a string as function argument input, and to allow it to be evaluated through dplyr using `sym()` and `!!`. This allows other non tidy operations to work in the function, including subsetting a data frame or just evaluating whether or not the argument is empty or not (which is my condition for my if function).

I referred to  https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html#unquoting-code

Using `sym()` turns the string into a symbol.
Symbols are required to be evaluated as a column in dplyr

```r
sym("NSE_name")
# NSE_name
```

Then use `!!` to inject the evaluation into the code

```r
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- function(order = NULL) {
  df <-
    tibble::tibble(NSE_name = c(0.2, -0.4, 1.7, 0.09, -0.6, -1))
  f2(order = order)
}

f2 <- function(order = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(order)) {
    
    ordered_df <- df %>% arrange(!!sym(order))
    return(ordered_df)
  }
  else print ("No order")
}

f1(order = "NSE_name")
f1()
```